# How to compare cell to a column and if match replace row?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to match two columns in two worksheets. If they match I want the row from sheet 1 to replace the row in sheet 2.

I came close but now I need to overwrite this row.

I tried selection.paste but that did not work.

I tried this:

```
Sub Loop_Example()

Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long

Sheets("Mutatie overzicht bezetting").Range("B5:AC5").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("BEZETTING 2020").Activate
With ActiveSheet
    .Select
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "B")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = Sheets("Mutatie overzicht bezetting").Range("C5") Then .EntireRow.Select
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. `Cells(Rows.Count, Sheets("BEZETTING 2020"))` is not valid, the second argument needs to be a column not a worksheet. You need sheet references throughout your code.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by SJR, your syntax is way off on the third line. Also you're missing sheet references, making your code fairly confusing. Please see below code to be a closer approximation to what you need:

```
Sub LoopThroughCities()

Dim LstRw As Long, ThsRw As Long, ThsEMPLOYEE As String

With Sheets("Bezetting 2020")
    LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

ThsEMPLOYEE = InputBox("Which employee do you want to search for?")

If Len(ThsEMPLOYEE) = 0 Then Exit Sub

For ThsRw = 2 To LstRw

    With Sheets("Sheettocopyfrom")
        If .Cells(ThsRw, 5).Value = ThsEMPLOYEE Then .Cells(ThsRw, 22).Resize(, 3).Copy Sheets("Sheettocopyto").Cells(ThsRw, 22)
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Plutian, I am sorry I am fairly new to this. I tried your code but it replaces the first row instead of the row that it matched. If it helps it needs to compare cell c5 of sheet 1 with column B of sheet 2. Then replace the row in column b of sheet 2 with row A5:AC5 of sheet 1.

Comment: This is not what the code in your original question does at all. Has it been specifically written for this task? If so you are approaching this completely incorrect.

Comment: No, I tried to edit one of my previous codes. Based on things I found online.